# DSolve solution for 1st order PDE involving complex number does not match initial condition

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, symbolic, complex, boundary-conditions

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier, persisting through 13.2.1.**

---

[Mathematica 12.0.0.0, MacOS X x86 (64bit)]

Trying to solve

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
DSolveValue[
  D[F[a, t], t] == 2 I a F[a, t] + 2 (a + 2 I a^2) D[F[a, t], a] && 
   F[a, 0] == E^(I a Q), F[a, t], {a, t}] // FullSimplify
```

returns

```
(E^((a E^(2 t) Q)/(I - 2 a (1 + E^(2 t)))) Sqrt[(
 1 + 2 I a)/(-I + 2 a (1 + E^(2 t)))])/Sqrt[I - 2 a]
```

For $t=0$ this evaluates to $$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+2 i a}{4a-i}}e^{\frac{a Q}{i-4a}}}{\sqrt{i-2a}}$$

which does not match the initial condition $F[a,0]=e^{i a Q}$.

Any idea where the problem lies?

Comment: I will delete my answer to check it again later. It does satisfy the IC, but can't make it satisfy the pde itself and I do not see why now, while Mathematica solution satisfies the pde but not the IC. So I might have something wrong in my solution since it only satisfies the IC. Will look at it again later if I can.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Are there any conditions on `a` and `t?` For instance, are they both non-negative real numbers?

Comment: Same behavior in v13.2. The sample can be simplified a bit to: `DSolveValue[{D[F[a, t], t] == a (1 + I a) D[F[a, t], a], F[a, 0] == a}, F[a, t], {a, t}] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @AlephBeth please report and raise this bug issue with support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This interesting question can be answered as follows.  First, obtain the solution without an initial condition.

```
DSolveValue[D[F[a, t], t] == 2 I a F[a, t] + 2 (a + 2 I a^2) D[F[a, t], a], 
     F[a, t], {a, t}]
(* C[1][1/4 (4 t - 2 I ArcTan[2 a] + 2 Log[a] - Log[1 + 4 a^2])]/Sqrt[I - 2 a] *)
```

Not surprisingly, `DSolve` has used the Method of Characteristics to obtain this answer.  See the Introduction to [Symbolic Solutions to PDEs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicSolutionsOfPDEs.html).  The solution is given by constant values along characteristics:

```
cn = Numerator[%][[1]]
(* 1/4 (4 t - 2 I ArcTan[2 a] + 2 Log[a] - Log[1 + 4 a^2]) *)
```

divided by `Sqrt[I - 2 a]`.  So, to obtain the solution for any `{a, t}`, trace back along the corresponding characteristic to `t = 0`, find the value there, and divide it by `Sqrt[I - 2 a]`.  To relate `(a, t}` to `{a0, 0}`, solve

```
Solve[cn == (cn /. t -> 0 /. a -> a0), a0] // FullSimplify // Flatten
(* {a0 -> (a E^t)/((-1 - 4 I a) Cosh[t] + Sinh[t]), 
    a0 -> (a E^t)/(Cosh[t] + (-1 - 4 I a) Sinh[t])} *)
```

The first expression leads to the incorrect result identified in the question.  The second expression, however, leads to the correct result.

```
sol = Exp[I Q a0] Sqrt[I - 2 a0]/Sqrt[I - 2 a] /. %[[2]]
(* (E^((I a E^t Q)/(Cosh[t] + (-1 - 4 I a) Sinh[t])) 
   Sqrt[I - (2 a E^t)/(Cosh[t] + (-1 - 4 I a) Sinh[t])])/Sqrt[I - 2 a] *)
```

That this result is correct can be verified by

```
FullSimplify[Unevaluated[{D[F[a, t], t] == 
    2 I a F[a, t] + 2 (a + 2 I a^2) D[F[a, t], a], F[a, 0] == E^(I a Q)}] 
    /. {F[a, t] -> sol, F[a, 0] -> (sol /. t -> 0)}]
(* {True, True} *)
```

I suspect that `DSolve` obtained the incorrect result in the question, because it did not handle branch cuts in the complex plane correctly.  By the way, in the course of investigating this problem, I obtained a simpler but equivalent solution,

```
Sqrt[I - ((2*I)*a*E^(2*t))/(I - 2*a + 2*a*E^(2*t))]/
    E^((a*E^(2*t)*Q)/(I - 2*a + 2*a*E^(2*t)))/Sqrt[I - 2 a]]
```

The derivation is a bit long.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I suspected this was a bug, but it is good to have some more experienced Mathematica user check it.